# Forçar aparecer extensão ao fazer download via javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, download

Tenho essa tela, de redimensionamento de imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
   quando clico em download, aparece essa tela pra salvar o arquivo, mas como podem ver, o arquivo aparece sem a extensão, como posso fazer pra o arquivo aparecer com a extensão automaticamente quando for salvar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tenho o seguinte codigo que faz o download:

js:

```
$('.js-crop').on('click', download);

download = function(){
    //Find the part of the image that is inside the crop box
      var canvas,
      left = $('.resize-image').offset().left - $container.offset().left,
      top =  $('.resize-image').offset().top - $container.offset().top,
      width = $('.resize-image').width(),
      height = $('.resize-image').height();

      canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image_target, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
      //var src = $('.resize-image').attr('src');
      //alert(src);
      //canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64");
      var ImageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64");
      ImageData = ImageData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
      document.location.href = ImageData;
  }
```

html:

```
<div class="content">
                <div class="component">
                    <img class="resize-image" src="img/image.jpg" alt="image for resizing">
                    <button class="btn-crop js-crop">Download<img class="icon-crop" src="img/crop.svg"></button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /content -->
```

Tem alguma forma de fazer isso? pode ser com php tbm se for necessário.
nesse link está o meu codigo full até o momento:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ptiq8h5y4r4akc/ImageResizeCropCanvas.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro sempre declare a função antes de usa-las ou definir ao `.on` ou então use neste formato `function ...()` ao invés deste `... = function()`.

Pra resolver o problema você deve criar um link usando algo como `<a download="nome.jpeg" href="...">` dinamicamente, assim:

```
$('.js-crop').on('click', download);

function download(){
    //Find the part of the image that is inside the crop box
      var canvas,
      left = $('.resize-image').offset().left - $container.offset().left,
      top =  $('.resize-image').offset().top - $container.offset().top,
      width = $('.resize-image').width(),
      height = $('.resize-image').height();

      canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image_target, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
      //var src = $('.resize-image').attr('src');
      //alert(src);
      //canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64");
      var ImageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64");
      ImageData = ImageData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");


      var ImageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
      ImageData = ImageData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");

      //Define o nome do arquivo
      this.download = "download.png";

      //Seta a url data:
      this.href = ImageData;
  }
```

e troque button por `<a>`:

```
<div class="content">
            <div class="component">
                <img class="resize-image" src="img/image.jpg" alt="image for resizing">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-crop js-crop">Download<img class="icon-crop" src="img/crop.svg"></a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /content -->
```

### Detalhes extras

Isto está errado `canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64");` o correto é isto:

- `canvas.toDataURL();` e `canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` pra PNG
- `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");` pra imagens JPEG

Comment: @guiilherme tem que fazer aguma coisa no  html além disso do javascript? porque aqui assim não funcionou, nem é chamado a função download...

Comment: não aparece nada, por isso disse (acho) que não é chamado a função download.

Comment: ta só na minha maquina... que site que posso usar pra hospedar isso?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ptiq8h5y4r4akc/ImageResizeCropCanvas.zip?dl=0  ta aí o link tbm...

Comment: não usei o codepen pq são alguns niveis de pastas e arquivos, n da muito certo usando ele aqui...

Comment: @AlexandreMartinsMontebelo corrigi o código.